# Swagger not loading in ASP.NET Core WebAPI application when using GRPC service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, grpc

I'm currently working on a project where I have a shared GRPC library containing proto files for both the client and server. The library is then included in a main ASP.NET Core WebAPI project. The GRPC functionality is working as expected, but I'm facing an issue with Swagger documentation not loading.

In WebAPIProject, I've added a reference to GRPCLibrary and included the necessary services in Startup.cs:

```
// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other configurations

    services.AddGrpc();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIProject", Version = "v1" });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ... other configurations

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPIProject v1");
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Despite these configurations, when I navigate to the Swagger UI (/swagger/index.html), I'm not able to see the documentation. It seems like the GRPC-related components are interfering with Swagger.
Has anyone faced a similar issue when combining GRPC with Swagger documentation in an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Swagger page should be loaded without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out multiple solutions found that there might be a conflict between the GRPC service name and Swagger. In this case, changing the GRPC service name from "Controller" to something else, like "Actuator," resolved the issue.

For example, if your GRPC service was originally named PublishController, try renaming it to PublishActuator. This change should not affect the functionality of your GRPC service but can prevent conflicts with Swagger in certain scenarios.

After making this change, regenerate your GRPC files and try accessing Swagger UI again. This simple adjustment resolved the Swagger documentation loading issue in my project.